# How to protect comments from being hacked

Tags: php, security, code-injection

My code uses this:

`Method - POST`

`fopen` then `fwrite` then `fclose` which writes in comments.
HTML Then opens comments. HTML by

```
<?php
  require 'comments.html'; 
?>
```

Comment: *"How to protect comments from being hacked"* - Google XSS (cross-site injection)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `require()`, as it will execute any PHP code in `comments.html`.

Use `readfile()` instead, which just copies the file to the output buffer.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php